# How to make the Promise lazy?

Tags: concurrency, promise, f#, hopac

```
open System
open System.Threading
open Hopac
open Hopac.Infixes

let hello what = job {
  for i=1 to 3 do
    do! timeOut (TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.0)
    do printfn "%s" what
}

run <| job {
  let! j1 = Promise.start (hello "Hello, from a job!")
  do! timeOut (TimeSpan.FromSeconds 0.5)
  let! j2 = Promise.start (hello "Hello, from another job!")
  //do! Promise.read j1
  //do! Promise.read j2
  return ()
}

Console.ReadKey()
```

```
Hello, from a job!
Hello, from another job!
Hello, from a job!
Hello, from another job!
Hello, from a job!
Hello, from another job!
```

This is one of the examples [from the Hopac documentation](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Docs/Programming.md#starting-and-waiting-for-jobs). From what I can see here, even if I do not explicitly call `Promise.read j1` or `Promise.read j2` the functions still get run. I am wondering if it is possible to defer doing the promised computation until they are actually run? Or should I be using `lazy` for the purpose of propagating lazy values?

Looking at the documentation, it does seem like Hopac's promises are supposed to be lazy, but I am not sure how this laziness is supposed to be manifested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a demonstration of laziness, consider the following example.

```
module HopacArith

open System
open Hopac

type S = S of int * Promise<S>

let rec arith i : Promise<S> = memo <| Job.delay(fun () ->
    printfn "Hello"
    S(i,arith (i+1)) |> Job.result
    )

let rec loop k = job {
    let! (S(i,_)) = k
    let! (S(i,k)) = k
    printfn "%i" i
    Console.ReadKey()
    return! loop k
    }

loop (arith 0) |> run
```

```
Hello
0
Hello
1
Hello
2
```

Had the values not been memoized, every time the enter is pressed, there would be two `Hello`s printed per iteration. This behavior can be seen if `memo <|` is removed.

There are some further points worth making. The purpose of `Promise.start` is not specifically to get memoizing behavior for some job. `Promise.start` is similar to `Job.start` in that if you bind a value using `let!` or `>>=` for example, it won't block the workflow until work is done. However compared to `Job.start`, `Promise.start` does give an option to wait for the scheduled job to be finished by binding on the nested value. And unlike `Job.start` and similarly to regular .NET tasks, it is possible to extract the value from a concurrent job started using `Promise.start`.

Lastly, here is an interesting tidbit I've discovered while playing with promises. It turns out, a good way of turning a `Job` into an `Alt` is to turn it into an `Promise` first and then upcast it.

```
module HopacPromiseNonblocking

open System
open Hopac
open Hopac.Infixes

Alt.choose [
    //Alt.always 1 ^=>. Alt.never () // blocks forever
    memo (Alt.always 1 ^=>. Alt.never ()) :> _ Alt // does not block
    Alt.always 1 >>=*. Alt.never () :> _ Alt // same as above, does not block
    Alt.always 2
    ]
|> run
|> printfn "%i" // prints 2

Console.ReadKey()
```

Uncommenting that first case would cause the program to block forever, but if you memoize the expression first that it is possible to get what would be backtracking behavior had the regular alternatives been used.